# Sysprep: "You must be an administrator"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sysprep

I am trying to sysprep a VM running Server 2012 R2.  When I run `sysprep.exe` *as an administrator* I get the following modal:

```
---------------------------
System Preparation Tool 3.14
---------------------------
You must be an administrator to run this application.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

If I click OK, sysprep exits.

I am 100% administrator and I 100% am executing it in admin mode.  I've tried `Right Click -> Run As Administrator` and running from an admin Command Prompt.

How do I get `sysprep.exe` to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to incorrectly configured group policy.  To determine this, I used this Microsoft KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/270032 and checked each permission with RSoP.  It turns out the "Administrators" group was removed from these policies.  Adding them back allowed sysprep to run.